# CQRS implementation for iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, cqrs

I'm working with CQRS (`Command and Query Responsibility Segregation`) and looking for an iOS implementation/library for it, any idea where i can find it?

Thanks.

Comment: CQRS is a pattern. What kind of implementation are you looking for ?

Comment: i want a library that implement the CQRS pattern. 
e.g. implementation for Events and Command Busses,.... etc

Answer (score 4):

CQRS can be a good fit for **occasionally connected clients** especially when you add **Event Sourcing**. They normally go hand in hand but CQRS can be done without ES. I do not know iOS but the same principles can apply. Have a peek [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/03/14/occasionally-connected-scenarios-it-doesn-t-have-to-be-complicated.aspx).

A good talk by **Greg Young** (one of the CQRS leading experts) can be found here: [CQRS, not just for server systems](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/cqrs-not-just-for-server-systems)

Keep in mind that CQRS is a **pattern** (not a framework) that you can apply to your solution (application).

CQRS is going a bit "more mainstream" - see [MS Patterns and Practices](http://cqrsjourney.github.com/) page for more in depth info on the first link.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should try MVVM.
CQRS is not something that should be used in mobile application.

UPDATE: I was wrong, CQRS is also pretty good to be applied on mobile dev, but it has less benefits than on web-dev

Comment: This sounds more like a comment, not like an answer. And by the way, why not CQRS? I'd say it depends on the application, but I can definitely see CQRS in the model layer of a mobile application properly implementing MVS or MVVC pattern.

Comment: CQRS is pattern, what helps you write more scalable application. Mobile app doesn't need to be scaled. As I understand author just whant to use commands in application. That's why I advised MVVM.

Comment: sorry what is the MVVM?? note that my original purpose is to use Commands and events in the application